# How does Verilog decide when events happen "simultaneously"?

Tags: verilog, race-condition, simultaneous

I know Verilog for only like 2 months, 3 months tops. I am absolutely frustrated about this one thing, which I would refer to as *race condition* if it was happening in some other, non-HDLanguage I know. Here are the files in their most simplified form, describing the case:

The `circuit.v`

```
module circuit(f, x, clk, rst);

    output f;
    input x, clk, rst;

    wire d, q;

    d_flip_flop flipper (q, d, clk, rst);

    assign f = q;
    assign d = x;

endmodule
```

The `d_flip_flop.v`

```
module d_flip_flop(q, d, clk, rst);

    output reg q;
    input d, clk, rst;

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
    begin
        if (rst)
            q <= 1'b0;
        else
            q <= d;
    end

endmodule
```

And I test these with this `tester.v`

```
module tester;

    reg x, clk, rst;
    wire f;

    circuit uut (f, x, clk, rst);

    initial clk <= 0;
    always #10 clk <= ~clk;

    initial
    begin
        x <= 0;
        rst <= 0;

        rst <= #2 1;
        rst <= #4 0;

        #10 x <= 1;
    end

endmodule
```

And here's the waveform I get:

[image: waveform]

What I see from that waveform is that Verilog has decided that it should first process the change in `clk`, hence perform the `q <= d;`; and only then process the change in `x`, hence perform `assign d = x;`.

What I said there probably doesn't even make sense in the hardware, but whatever.

Now: I have people around me, so called the assistants of the lecture, more experienced and presumably more knowledgeable, claiming that a *properly written* Verilog sequential module always considers the changes as happened, as the clock hits posedge. Even in this extremely simple example, however, I see it to be otherwise (and probably not necessarily, either).

So, the question is, what should I be doing to turn this into a *properly written* Verilog sequential module? How could I make my bad code to be a good one like the others? Or is there just no such thing, and Verilog is just proudly non-deterministic in such cases?

Comment: Instead of using `d_flip_flop flipper (q, d, clk, rst);` use `d_flip_flop flipper (q, x, clk, rst);` in toplevel module.

Answer (score -1):

The behaviour that I've always seen in this situation is: first the clock raises from low to high and that generates a posedge event. When this happens, right side expressions inside nonblocking assignments are read at its current values.

I cannot be more specific about this, but my assumption is that if a right side expression changes at the same time the clock generates the posedge event, the value read is undetermined. Real world flip flops need a certain amount of time for the input signal to settle before it can be considered valid (set-up time). If this set-up time is not met, the value stored by the flip flop would be the previous value of the input signal. So, simulators try to mimic this behaviour.

A proper designed sequential system should allow changes to input signals only when the active clock transition is not yet happened. For example: the SPI protocol specifies that the data signal must change in the opposite clock transition to that is used to accept the current value of data.

[image: SPI timing]

Data (MOSI and MISO signals) change at the falling edge of SCLK. Data is read or written at the rising edge of SCLK. Notice that at that moment, data is stable in both data lines so set-up and hold times constraints are met and the current value is effectively stored in the shift register that SPI uses.

This described behaviour should be consistent and completely deterministic, as it's the basis of many known hardware constructions such as shift registers and counters:

```
module shiftreg2bits (
  input wire clk,
  input wire i,
  output wire [1:0] o
  );

  reg ff1 = 1'b0;
  reg ff2 = 1'b0;
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    ff1 <= i;
    ff2 <= ff1;
  end
  assign o = {ff1,ff2};
endmodule
```

At the beginning, time `#0`, `o = 00`.

Assuming `i = 1` when the first `clk` event happens:

- `ff1` takes the **CURRENT** value of `i`, that is, `1`
- `ff2` takes the **CURRENT** value of `ff1`, that is, `0`. `ff2` does not take `1` because the mechanism for `ff1` to store the value `1` that have just read takes some time (one time unit in a simulation with no delays given, and a specific non zero time that is dependent of the hardware for real flip flops, the so called "[propagation delay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Propagation_delay)"), so the output of `ff1` is still `0` when the `clk` event happens.
- So, `o = 10`

Answer (score -1):

To create a properly written model and avoid race conditions, you should first change your nonblocking assignments to blocking assignments.  Blocking assignments will update the signals immediately as you intended.

Notice all the '<=' turned into '='.

Verilog's blocking assignment will block (i.e. stop) and update the signal right away.

The nonblocking assignments you originally had written will update the left-hand-side (LHS) after a delta delay.  The nonblocking assignment was originally intended to model the clock-to-Q delay of sequential logic (a flop).

```
module tester;

reg x, clk, rst;
wire f;

circuit uut (f, x, clk, rst);

initial clk = 0;
always #10 clk = ~clk;

initial
begin
    x = 0;
    rst = 0;

    rst = #2 1;
    rst = #4 0;

    #10 x = 1;
end
```

[Verilog Gotcha!](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.be%2Fbooks%3Fid%3D_VGghBpoK6cC%26lpg%3DPR12%26ots%3DF2kIzTXUA3%26dq%3Dsutherland%2520gotcha%252029%26hl%3Den%26pg%3DPA64%23v%3Donepage%26q%26f%3Dfalse)

[image]